# Recommended Resources for Data Compression Research

Tags: algorithm, compression

I'm looking for recommended resources on data compression; any studies on techniques, data structure and/or algorithms; any useful resources related to research, any books, organizations or any other information would be helpful.

I know it's kind of a general query, but just interested in expanding my knowledge on the subject matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this one: http://datacompression.info/  (a portal on data compression)

Some interesting articles:

- Arithmetic coding:     http://www.dogma.net/markn/articles/arith/part1.htm
- Huffman coding:     http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/2151/huffman.html
- LZW:     http://marknelson.us/1989/10/01/lzw-data-compression/
- BWT:     http://marknelson.us/1996/09/01/bwt/

Answer (score 1):

[This 1987 survey paper](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/45072.45074) on Data Compression covers the first 40 years or so and seems to be good.

On a side note, in the category of "expanding [your] knowledge on the subject matter" is [this BBS Documentary](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=4358667732166276191) of the .[ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_(file_format)) vs. .[ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) controversy of the early 1990s. It's a fascinating look at the human side of these compression "wars."

I was an active BBS user at the time and didn't realize the full story when it was going on.

Answer (score 1):

My 2015 paper [A Survey Of Architectural Approaches for Data Compression in Cache and Main Memory Systems](https://www.academia.edu/12429529/A_Survey_Of_Architectural_Approaches_for_Data_Compression_in_Cache_and_Main_Memory_Systems)  (permalink [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=7110612)) reviews many compression algorithms and also techniques for using them in modern processors. It reviews both research-grade and commercial-grade compression algorithms/techniques, so you may find many related compression techniques from the references cited in the paper.

Comment: Seems to be more about application in the memory hierarchy of _large_ systems than about stream/string/block compression techniques; and to cover a lot of ground.